# How to change Tab-completed content at runtime in Haskeline?

Tags: haskell, haskeline

I want to write a text interface, which provides some default commands. This program supports tab completion of those commands.

This program also records user inputs and stores it in `StateData`. And now I want this program to support tab completion of those user inputs. For example:

```
*Main > main
> read a<tab> -- press tab and no suggestions (read is a default command)
> read abcde
...
> read a<tab> -- press tab
abcde         -- suggestions
```

Is it possible to do that without using unsafe mechanism like `IORef`? Is there a way to pass updated `st` from `loop` (in `repl`) to `replSettings startState` (in `repl`)?

I am new to Haskeline and thanks for your time.

```hs
repl :: StateData -> IO()
repl startState                    =  runInputT (replSettings startState) $ loop startState
  where
    loop :: StateData              -> InputT IO ()
    loop st                        =  do
      inputL                       <- getInputLine "> "
      case inputL                  of
           Nothing                 -> return ()
           Just "quit"             -> outputStrLn "--Exited--" >> return ()
           Just ipt                -> do (opt, st')     <- process ipt `runStateT` st
                                         ...
                                         loop st'

replSettings :: StateData -> Settings IO
replSettings st =
  Settings
    { complete       = replCompletion st,
      historyFile    = Just "history.txt",
      autoAddHistory = True
    }

replCompletion :: StateData -> CompletionFunc IO
replCompletion st = completeWordWithPrev Nothing [' '] st (\x y -> return $ completionGenerator x y)

completionGenerator :: String -> String -> StateData -> [Completion]
completionGenerator "" c st = 
  commandSuggestion c (updatesSuggestions st) -- I wish to update it at run time
completionGenerator p  c st = ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IORef` isn’t unsafe; you’re already in `IO`, so it’s a perfectly reasonable way to add mutable state here.

But if you want to avoid `IO`, you can simply use `StateT StateData IO` as the underlying monad for `InputT`, and thus the completion function in `Settings`. It seems you’re already trying to use `StateT` anyway. Here’s a complete example that just adds every entry to a list and autocompletes them naïvely:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT, evalStateT, get, modify)
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)
import System.Console.Haskeline

type StateData = [String]

main :: IO ()
main = repl []

repl :: StateData -> IO ()
repl startState
  = flip evalStateT startState
  $ runInputT replSettings loop
  where
    loop :: InputT (StateT StateData IO) ()
    loop = do
      inputL <- getInputLine "> "
      case inputL of
        Nothing -> pure ()
        Just "quit" -> outputStrLn "--Exited--"
        Just ipt -> do
          -- Just add each entry to the state directly.
          lift $ modify (ipt :)
          loop

replSettings :: Settings (StateT StateData IO)
replSettings = Settings
  { complete       = replCompletion
  , historyFile    = Just "history.txt"
  , autoAddHistory = True
  }

replCompletion :: CompletionFunc (StateT StateData IO)
replCompletion = completeWordWithPrev Nothing " " completionGenerator

completionGenerator :: String -> String -> StateT StateData IO [Completion]
completionGenerator prefix suffix = do
  st <- get
  -- Trivial completion that just ignores the suffix.
  pure $ fmap (\ s -> Completion s s True)
    $ filter (prefix `isPrefixOf`) st
```

The completion generator could also be written using `MonadState` (from `mtl`) to insulate it from being able to access `IO`, and other code could likewise use this pure state while being agnostic to `IO`. But otherwise, since you’re already in `IO` in this code, `StateT StateData IO` / `get` / `modify` are no different than `ReaderT (IORef StateData) IO` / `readIORef` / `modifyIORef`.

In fact, if you put an `IORef` *in* `StateData`, supposing it’s a more complex record type in your code, the latter is a good way to make some parts of it mutable and others immutable.

```
data StateData = StateData
  { mutableThing   :: !(IORef Thing)
  , immutableStuff :: !Stuff
  …
  }
```